# What's the difference between eating 2000 Calories at once compared to eating 4 times a day at 500 Calories?

Tags: nutrition, calories, daily-caloric-intake, eating-habits, recommended-daily-intake

I wonder is there any difference in how many times I eat per day?

Let's say I eat one big meal in the morning at 2000 Cal (at 9am). Is that any different than having 4 meals at 500 Cal throughout the day (at 9am, 1pm, 5pm, 9pm)?

I think I will be hungry by the end of the day if I eat just once in the morning. But I won't be hungry if I eat 4 times a day at smaller portions? How is that possible?

Which way is it better to eat? Maybe twice a day at 1000 Cal? (9am and like 4pm?)

Head scratch.

Comment: Interesting question, but sadly off-topic for this forum.

Comment: Not only off topic, but cross posted. Don't do that.